# Fields do Advanced Custom Fields não aparecem no front-end

Tags: wordpress

Estou tendo um problema com o plugin ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) para WordPress, cheguei até a pagar os $25 pelo add-on Repeater Fields , mas não sei se fiz um bom negócio.
Eu olhei a documentação e lá diz que preciso apenas inserir apenas o seguinte código: `<?php the_field('NOME DO CAMPO AQUI'); ?>` , porém não aparece no front-end.
Já passaram por este problema?

Aqui ele funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui ele não aceita mais o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não utilizo "templates", escrevo todo HTML e insiro o PHP, tento também usar o minimo de plugins possíveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para tentar reproduzir e localizar o problema é melhor você mostrar o código real que está usando e uma captura de tela da sua configuração do Field no backend. A solução do igrossiter abaixo é legal, lembro de uma vez já ter precisado usar algo parecido. Faz tempo que não trabalho com isso, mas acho que os *Repeater Fields* tem um modo de acesso diferente. . . . Só pra tirar uma dúvida: se você desabilitar todos os outros plugins e usar um tema padrão, o problema continua?

Comment: Desativei "todos", ainda assim não funcionou. Estou inserindo os prints logo abaixo.

Comment: Aqui ele funciona:
![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]


![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]


Aqui ele não aceita mais o código:

![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][3]


Eu não utilizo "templates", escrevo todo HTML e insiro o PHP, tento também usar o minimo de plugins possíveis.

![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][4]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mXDxz.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8dWJ.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vlPzI.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/21mHD.jpg

Comment: É melhor postar código puro que imagens de código, usando comentários em HTML ou PHP para indicar os pontos problemáticos. E em vez de adicionar informação nos comentários, **[edit]e** a pergunta para melhorá-la.

Comment: No seu exemplo (onde não aceita o código) não vejo você usando a sintaxe do Repeater Field.

Comment: Realmente não usei o Repeater Field, estou tendo problemas em fazer o loop funcionar então tentei uma "alternativa" que também não deu muito certo.

Comment: Bom, se a resposta do igrossiter não resolve o problema, ou se você quiser fazer o ACF funcionar, sugiro que você edite sua pergunta considerando o seguinte: **O que uma pessoa precisa pra reproduzir seu problema?** **`1)`** Código que possa ser copiado (não imagens) e indicação de onde deve ser inserido. **`2)`** Uma mostra da configuração do seu Field (sim imagens): `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf`

Answer (score 2):

Advanced Custom Fields salva os campos como *custom fields* normais do WordPress.
Com o ID do *post* e o código do *custom field* utilize a função [`get_post_custom()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom):

```php
get_post_custom($id_do_post);
```

Por exemplo:

```php
$opcoes = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
$minha_opcao = $opcoes['codigo_do_campo'][0];
// o index 0 é importante, pois get_post_custom
// retorna um array
```

Eu gosto de inserir a seguinte função auxiliadora no meu `functions.php`:

```php
function getDados($dado) {
    global $post;
    $opcoes = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());

    return $opcoes[$dado][0];
}
```

Dessa forma posso usar nos *loops*:

```php
$minha_opcao = getDados('codigo_do_campo');
```

Comment: Uma boa opção, mas no caso eu "preciso" usar o plugin ACF pois foi feito um investimento $$$ nele.

Comment: o ACF repeater né..., desculpe não poder te ajudar com ele.

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo que não funciona está localizado na home. Sua chamada está correta, porém para que funcione, precisa da chamada na página, seja um `query_posts ou the_post()`.

Comment: Obrigado Erlon, seu comentário me fez perceber que eu não estava linkando os "campos" as páginas corretas.